# How to limit number strings with crunch

Tags: brute-force, dictionary, crunch, wordlist

I'm currently trying to generate a very specific word list. The words generated should go like this:

```
crunch 9 9 -t @%%%%%%,,-o test.txt
```

But one of the constraints that I have given myself is that the numbers generated shouldn't go above a certain number, for example `z092348ZZ`. Where the first two digits shouldn't go above 09, the 3rd and 4th digits shouldn't go above 23 and the last pair of digits shouldn't go above 48 I have tried doing this: `crunch 9 9 -t @%%%%%%,, -e z092348ZZ -o test.txt`

But as you can imagine, it doesn't work that way since I eventually obtain:

```
a999999AA
```

and it goes on like that making a very heavy wordlist. I'm trying to make an efficient word list.

I don't know if there are other ways to achieve this using `sed`.

Comment: Maybe try hashcats mask processor, with custom charsets it should be possible

Comment: I'm not sure I would use crunch for this requirement. I'd script that.